# iphone- Best way to store data

Tags: ios, data-storage

I am working on a project that involves storing video, photo, audio, and text data. What would be the best way of doing this? I want to find the most efficient way possible before I start. The data will have to be editable also. When the user selects a tableview cell, a detailview will be displayed that shows all the data.

Comment: Well, what's wrong with simply putting them in your app's sandbox? In the documents folder or a subfolder of it.

Comment: What research have you done? Apple has extensive documentation on the sandbox, CoreData, and `NSCoding`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing on the file system definitely. Best practices indicate storing the photos and videos in photo album serves best, as users can access them without accessing your app also.Also to create a reference for yourself, you can store an identifier such as video or photoname in coredata.